# SVG polyline make responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

So I have the following example - https://jsfiddle.net/po2kddf4/ . I would like to make it full-width. So the desired outcome should be that the svg polylines cover the 100% height and 100% width.

**HTML:**

```css
.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <svg id="SvgjsSvg1071" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs">
  <defs id="SvgjsDefs1072"></defs>
  <polyline id="SvgjsPolyline1073" points="10,10 100,10 100,200 10,200 10,10" fill="#ffa500" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" style="cursor: pointer;"><title>Test 1</title></polyline>
  <polyline id="SvgjsPolyline1074" points="100,10 200,10 200,50 250,50 250,150 100,150 100,10" fill="#ffa500" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1;"><title>Test 2</title></polyline>
  </svg>
</div>
```

[image: Desired Result]

So the above image would be desired result. The proportion of the image size changes, to match the full-width of the block.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. In case someone else will search in future -

You can add viewBox parameter to svg tag, in this case we were interested in last two digits so `viewBox="0 0 250 200"` did the trick just fine. 250 is max x coordinate, and 200 is max y coordinate.

Comment: And in your particular example, change the box css height to percentage base